# CouchDB read restriction

Tags: couchdb, readonly

I have an app where i want to implement a chat/messaging service. I have to use CouchDB with PouchDB. My problem is that every user should be able to send a message to anyone, but only the receiver of the message can read this, but there is no way in CouchDB to restrict every user from reading the conversation doc. Database per user is also not a solution since there is no way for everyone to write to the corresponding database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CouchDB & PouchDB do not have per-document access control, only per-database. One solution to this is to have:

- a single database for sent messages residing on the server. The PouchDB clients write (but don't read) to this database by doing client->server one-way replication.
- a database per user on the server side with server->client one-way replication. This is how the PouchDB clients get received messages.
- on the server side, write some custom script to move documents from the central database to the per-user databases depending on the recipient

This is a similar approach to the one outlined in my [blog post about bus station displays](https://medium.com/ibm-watson-data-lab/custom-cloudant-replication-d0753284d834) which uses a serverless changes feed listener to route the messages. It's not ideal, but is one solution.